# Difference between loadClass() and forName()

Tags: java, reflection, classloader

Does anyone knows what is the different between:

```
Class clazz = getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass(className);
```

AND

```
Class clazz = Class.forName(className);
```

As i tried both, it gave me same result.

Answer (score 8):

`Class.forName(className)` execute the static initializer code blocks in the loaded class.

> A call to forName("X") causes the class named X to be initialized.

`getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass(className)` doesn't.

---

`Class.forName(className, false,  getClass().getClassLoader())` is the same as `getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass(className)`.

---

**Resources :**

- [javadoc - `Class.forName()`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String))
- [Javadoc - `ClassLoader.loadClass()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass(java.lang.String))
- [JLS - Initialization of Classes and Interfaces](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/execution.html#12.4)

Comment: Now that would be _really_ strange - you could get a class token of an uninitialized class via `ClassLoader.loadClass()`? How and when would that class supposed to get initialized then? I have serious doubts about any such difference.

Comment: When you load a class you don't initialize it, so it will be initialized when you'll use it (same behavior as other classes hard coded)

Comment: OK, I checked it further and you are right. +1 for you :-) For reference: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/execution.html#57946